# How do I correctly pass a UserControl that contains resources between two threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization, user-controls

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a while now and am just stumped. I have created a UserControl type (edited below) that i am trying to generate and serialize from a background thread.

The background thread generating the Control is marked as STA and uses a memory stream to pass the control.  However the control contains a data template in the UserControl.Resources section that is causing errors during deserialization.

Is it not possible to pass a user control containing a resource between threads without defining the resources in an external merged resource dictionary?

code:
UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_Base.Example">
 <UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type Example2}>
     <Example2View />
   </DataTemplate>
 </UserControl.Resources>
 <Grid>
  <StackPanel>
   <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding GetExamples}" />
  </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ThreadCode (Presented as a single thread):

```
            System.IO.MemoryStream streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            var testExample = new WPF_Base.Example();
            var test = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(testExample);

            var test2 = new System.IO.StringReader(test);
            var test3 = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(test2);
            var test4 = (WPF_Base.TestExample)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(test3); //Exception thrown here about key already existing in the dictionary
```

EDIT:
   The controls are being generated and built in the other thread for due to the possibly that user may be loading a file that contains many pieces of data (controls are in a MVVM pattern) that each are represented as a view on the screen.  During this process i would  still want the UI to be responsive and not appear to "lock". I guess i could stagger when the controls are rendered to the screen instead of all at once since that would be the major bottle neck with the views.

Comment: In MVVM, split the controls from their data.  See my edited answer.

Comment: The data and controls are split. The problem appears to be rendering all the controls at once. Which i now realize that creating them on the background thread won't fix since they are not rendered until displayed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
If you are indeed using the MVVM pattern, you should create your control on the main (UI) thread, create your object data on the other thread, and set it as the control's DataContext when it is available.  Better yet, don't create the control at all until each 'DataContext' becomes available.  This is a common way to keep your application responsive even when you may have to wait a long time for the data, say over the internet.

OLD --> About the first part of your question:
This isn't a threading problem.  In short, this is not working because when you try to deserialize the data, the runtime is trying to add the template, again, to the internal 'XAMLType' representation of your object.  This effect is not limited to templates however, any resource that you define will cause a problem when you attempt to load it in this fashion.  Even giving names, etc. to XAML elements in your control will cause problems.

EDIT:
The XAML serializer approach that you are trying to use is not what it is intended for.  Additionally, you don't want to create controls on another thread for the reason that you mention in you comment.

Comment: The problem with passing the object references is that when the main thread goes to use the generated control an exception is thrown. The exception is that only the thread that created a control can use it.